# const and rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11

Im trying to write an efficient list and node classes that have minimal code to iterate over them. However I'm having difficulty fulfilling all my criteria.  I want this code to be used safely in a multi-threaded environment and so if possible I want all the functions and arguments for iteration to be const to ensure no state is being written to ie its all read only.  So I wrote the below classes and iteration code:

```
template<typename _Type_>
class Node
{
    template<typename _Type_> friend class List;

public:
    Node() : m_Next(NULL) {}
    Node(const _Type_& value) : m_Value(value), m_Next(nullptr()) {}

    const _Type_& Get() const { return m_Value; }
    Node&& Next() const { return std::move(*m_Next); }

    operator _Type_ () const { return m_Value; }

    _Type_& operator->() { return m_Value; }
    const _Type_& operator->() const { return m_Value; }

    operator bool() const { return m_Next != nullptr(); }

private:
    _Type_  m_Value;
    Node*   m_Next;
};

template<typename _Type_>
class List
{
public:

    typedef Node<_Type_> Node;

    List() : m_Head(NULL) {}

    void AddHead( const _Type_& value )
    {
        Node* pNode = GE_NEW(Node, value); 

        pNode->m_Next = &m_Head;
        m_Head = *pNode; 
    }

    Node&& Head() const { return std::move(m_Head); }

private:
    Node m_Head;
};
```

and the all important iteration code:

```
RenderTargetList::Node&& renderTarget = m_Targets.Head();
while( renderTarget )
{
    if(renderTarget->Format() == format)
    {
        return renderTarget.Get();
    }

    renderTarget = renderTarget.Next();
}
```

But this doesn't compile as:

```
Node&& Head() const { return std::move(m_Head); }
```

returns a non const rvalue reference in a const function function ie it has to be:

```
const Node&& Head() const { return std::move(m_Head); }
```

instead, but then this doesn't work as the iteration code fails on the assignment:

```
renderTarget = renderTarget.Next();
```

because renderTarget must now be defined as:

```
const RenderTargetList::Node&& renderTarget = m_Targets.Head();
```

because head returns a const.  Basically I seem to be in a right mess of const, references, lvalues and rvalues.  Someone please help!

Thanks

Comment: Why is `m_Head` not a pointer?

Comment: I think the main problem here is the design of `Node`: It's a value type (because it contains/owns a *value*: the `m_Value` data member) but you seem to want to use it like a pointer-semantics type (using it as an iterator; assigning to it without changing the content of the list).

Comment: m_Head is not a pointer because if the list is empty it must not de-reference a nullptr hence the reason why Node has a bool cast operator.

Comment: Ok so Node has a value and a pointer but all I'm doing here is passing references around to these Node instances.  I'm not wanting to copy the Node instance around.  What I'm doing here doesn't seem to go against the rules of C++ but obviously it does the question is how to modify the code to meet my needs.

Comment: Don't return an rvalue-reference to the head! If the user uses that getter, your list would be corrupted, because internally the node was cleared. Except in rare casting cases, **never return rvalue-references. Return (almost) always by value, letting the compiler do optimizations.

Comment: Btw `_Type_` is a reserved identifier (IIRC). Don't use names that start with `_` plus a capital letter.

Comment: You are missleading one of the key points of C++ and move-semantics: Move semantics are only a new semantic to make more efficient passing temporaries around. From the user point of view, there should be no suitable difference in the code if there are move semantics or not. **Using rvalue references everywhere != efficient code (In fact, its just the inverse, because you break allmost all optimization oportunities)**.

Comment: A good guideline to get well performant code in modern C++ is: **Rely on value semantics, write clear (no low-level tricks) code, and let `-O3` do its job**

Comment: Oh, sorry: My comment about returning rvalue references and `std::move()`aplies to all getters.

Comment: Hmmm actually after rereading your aims, a `std::list<T>` should be sufficient: If you pass it around as a `std::list<T> const&` or its `const_iterators`, you cannot modify the list.

Comment: @dyp: _Type_ works perfectly fine in the project I work on.  Even if it did cause problems its trivial to change and benefits of using this more verbose naming convention over T, S and U are huge.

Comment: `_Type_` might get you in trouble sometime in the future. You are free to use `_type_`, `Type_` or `Type`, but using anything containing two `_` or beginning with a `_` and a capital letter is nonportable.

Comment: Formatting hint: Surround inline code with backticks `\`` ;)

Comment: I and my colleagues have been writing code for a few decades now on multiple platforms (well over ten) and its never been a problem once. But anyway this is off topic.

Comment: I can only tell you what the C++ Standard says about it, not *if* it'll ever be a problem with the compilers *you're* using. See §17.6.4.3.2 [global.names]

Comment: @Manu343726: thats a fair enough point maybe passing by value is the way to go. However if the value is a complex type how can I guarantee the compiler is not going to do a copy on renderTarget = renderTarget.Next() line (rather than passing by reference)?

Comment: `renderTarget = renderTarget.Next();` References can't be reassigned; this line just copies the contents of next into the contents of head, modifying your list, hence why you found `renderTarget` can't be `const`. Like @dyp says, you want pointer semantics.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the basic version of a list class. Note that the iterator type and the node type are two distinct types. This way, the node type can own the value, and the iterator type can have pointer semantics.

I'll post this as a community wiki, as it's rather a comment than a direct answer to the question.

```
template<typename Type>
class List
{
private:
    // note that for immutable nodes, we could store `Type const`
    // and for an immutable list, `Node const* const`
    struct Node
    {
        Type  m_Value;
        Node* m_pNext;
    };

    Node* m_pHead;

public:

    class const_iterator
    {
    private:
        Node const* m_pNode;
        friend List;
        const_iterator(Node* p_pNode) : m_pNode(p_pNode) {}

    public:
        const_iterator() : m_pNode(nullptr) {}

        explicit operator bool() const
        { return m_pNode; }

        const_iterator Next() const
        { return {m_pNode->m_pNext}; }

        Type const& Get() const
        { return m_pNode->m_Value; }

        friend bool operator!=(const_iterator const& lhs,
                               const_iterator const& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.m_pNode != rhs.m_pNode;
        }
    };

    List() : m_pHead(nullptr) {}
    ~List()
    {
        // delete nodes
    }
    List(List const&) = delete; // needs to be customized
    List& operator=(List const&) = delete; // this one, too

    // the only function that modifies the list:
    void AddHead( Type const& value )
    {
        Node* pNode = new Node{value, m_pHead};
        m_pHead = pNode;
    }

    const_iterator Head() const
    { return {m_pHead}; }
};
```

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    List<int> l;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) l.AddHead(i); 

    auto it = l.Head();
    while(it)
    {
        std::cout << it.Get() << ", ";
        it = it.Next();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not used to NSDMIs yet, it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused at to the point of const if your goal is thread safety -- const does not give you thread safe code, only considerate and well understood access patterns will give you thread safe code.

I have lost of code which is thread sfae which does not make use of const, and you will need to as well if you want to be able to keep the "AddHead" method which certainly in its current form is not thread safe.

If your code is threaded you will need to add mutex locks around the code where you are accessing shared data which could be modified or **read** by another thread -- the critical zones  -- from your code structure these critical zones could be very short lived, so not much of a penalty.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not calling AddHead here thats just included because of a copy and paste.  Ill remove it.  Using const obviously doesn't make your code thread safe per se but its a bloody good way of exposing areas that aren't thread safe.

Comment: Still doesn't matter -- unless this is an entirely read-only structure then you will need to create critical zones for synchronization between  threads.   If the structure is entirely read-only then it doesn't matter if you declare all your accesors const or not (apart from some compiler optimization which can be done on cost declarations)

Comment: Also you certainly shouldn't need to add mutex locks around shared data as it scales terribly far better to duplicate memory ie not share data or use atomic instructions.

Comment: Sure, if your threads do not share any state or access any shared variables, then you are fine -- but then there are no considerations needed for thread safety anyway.

Comment: If all you are doing is reading from it and you can make sure you never add to it at the same time which I can in my problem domain then in this scenario you don't need to lock.  I am sorry for not explaining this better however.

Comment: The problem is that in order for a member function that I want to be const to iterate through this loop it all needs to be const. The constness trickles down through everything.  Sure I could use mutable on the list but I'd prefer not to.